# Do email clients apply a specific ID to HTML emails?

Tags: css, html-email, email-client

I'm currently coding up an HTML email and it's a friggin nightmare. I'm getting pretty close to a perfect design, but my modifications are at the stage where one client's fix causes problems for another client's fix. I read somewhere (can't find) that outlook applies an #outlook ID to the body of the email. This would be life changing if it happened for many clients... Google is being fruitless too- so can anybody share some wise words of wisdom on this topic?

Thanks,

~Harley

Comment: For anyone getting the same nightmare, I use MJML, a framework that makes it easy to design responsive emails that work on most of the HTML clients. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

My words of wisdom are based on experience with the nightmare called HTML emails.
Some will always apply their own garbage to many elements. So when you ask if they add an ID, I ask add to what? Your first element? all elements? Yup. Many times they do. Many don't mess with much. Depends on the mail client.

I have done HTML emails for many large name clients. In the end the best practice is to go WAY back to raw, old school html. Forget CSS. If you design and implement your HTML newsletter based entirely off the old rules of 4.0 transitional HTML and all the inferior styling methods from the hayday of code, then you should be good in all clients.

You can add css if you want but it's dependencies like that that can and most likely will be more like a patch than a solution.

Comment: Hey mate, totally getting you on the nightmare. I came into web design right after table layouts were scrapped in favour of CSS2 so it's been a mega learning curve for me. I'm doing that for the most part- like I said below, my main problem is that in `background-position: right -4px;` webkit based clients render it perfectly, however multiple others are doubling it. kinda a pain. specific selectors would solve this for the most part... thanks for the wise words :)

Comment: And that method alone shows you're using a background image, which I would discourage for html newsletters. I tell all clients that all images must be block level and nothing dynamic floating over them. Like dates or headers or anything. In an ideal world, selectors could handle that. But many mail clients will just strip out all css declarations except basic ones. No list exists that I know of. But things like z-index, position, etc - are almost always removed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not uncommon for Outlook to add IDs, MSO tags, and loads of other crap. Just view the source of the HTML email after it's passed through outlook and you'll see what I mean.

It's important to set your client's expectation that HTML emails will never be pixel perfect across all email clients. Support is getting better, but background images, CSS, and the box model are shaky at best.

The best advice I can give is to start with a [MailChip](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/) template, and work from there. Otherwise, simple, table based designs work out best across all clients.

Also from MailChip (http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/top-html-email-coding-mistakes/)

> Linked CSS files won't always work in HTML email, so you've got to use
>   inline or embedded CSS. Normally, when you code a web page, you put
>   the embedded CSS code in between your  tags. But lots of email
>   applications (especially browser based ones) ***strip out the HEAD and
>   BODY tags of your HTML email***, so your CSS will get stripped too.

Comment: Also, don't make the mistake of thinking that a large name like campaign monitor or mail chimp are the end say in html newsletter design. I've have to completely rewrite newsletters that were template failures from campaign monitor - a so called expert on the subject. They try to pile on work arounds to find a happy medium for all clients but in the end it is just extra garbage that doesn't need to be there. want it done right? go back to the basics until everyone is caught up to a livable standard - or accept that there is never going to be a balance on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<html>
<body>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]–>
gte mso 9
<!–[if gte mso 9]><![endif]–>

<!--[if !gte mso 9]><!---->
!gte mso 9
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
!mso
<!--<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```